# Find gain cross over frequency?

Tags: matlab

For G(s) = K/(s(s+0.5)(s+4.6)) **with K a scalar to choose**,

```
G(s) =   
            1
  ---------------------
  s^3 + 5.1 s^2 + 2.3 s
```

find the **gain cross over frequency** which would give a 45 degree phase margin.

I solved this using `sisotool` and according to me my answer is 0.42 but my tutorial sheet shows the answer to be 0.23. Please can someone help me with this?

Comment: Be more explicit about what you're having problems with. A couple sentences would do.

Comment: have a look at my final edit. There must be a mistake in your question.

Comment: Is my answer for gain cross over frequency which is 0.42 correct according to this particular question ?

Comment: Sorry! I thought you're looking for the gain, not the frequency. 0.42 rad/s is correct! Have a look at my edit. Please also accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function is finding the gain:

```
function findGainM()

phasemargin = 45; 

s = tf([1 0],1);               % definition of Laplace-Operator
A = 1/(s*(s+0.5)*(s+4.6));     % Transferfunction with K=1

disp(A)
fun = @(x) findGain(x,phasemargin,A); 
fzero(fun,1);

% display result
K = evalin('base','K');
w = evalin('base','wco');
disp( ['absolute gain: ' num2str(K)] )
disp( ['logarithmic gain: ' num2str(20*log10(K)) ' dB'] )
disp( ['crossover frequency: ' num2str(w) ' rad/s'] )
disp( ['crossover frequency: ' num2str(w/(2*pi)) ' Hz'] )

figure(1)
bodeplot(K*A)
grid on;

end

function rootPhase = findGain(w,phasemargin,A)
[mag,phase] = bode(A,w);
disp([mag,phase])
rootPhase = 180 - phasemargin + phase;
gain = 1/mag;
assignin('base','K',gain)
assignin('base','wco',w)
end
```

returning:

```
absolute gain: 1.2536
logarithmic gain: 1.963 dB
crossover frequency: 0.4169 rad/s
crossover frequency: 0.066352 Hz
```

[image]

---

I also checked the `sisotool` getting the same results like my function.

[image]

Comment: Just a tip: you can define the Laplace operator this way `s=tf('s');`