# How to programatically find the magnitude and frequency for a given phase in a bode plot?

Tags: matlab

If I have a Plant let's say

> Gp(s) = 1/(s+1)

I can find the Phase Margin

Using MATLAB commands

```
Gp = tf([1],[1 1]);
[G P] = margin(Gp);
```

My question is what if I want to know the phase over frequency in a specific Gain Over Frequency. How do I find it without looking to bode plot?

Usually I find it by the command bode(Gp) and move the mouse over the specific gain that I want to know the phase margin on it.

For my previous example The Gain Over Frequency is 0.363 at -20 Phase Over Frequency.

How do I write it as a command not looking in the bode diagram?

Thanks in advance

Comment: this is basically a math question. You can find a similar question and answer [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20453770/find-gain-cross-over-frequency/20454048#20454048)

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user2485710: no. Rather [Electrical Engineering SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com) - but actually the OP should do some research about control systems and what is to do mathematically, which is quite easy. Then it's a programming problem again, solvable with `fzero` as described in the answer linked above. For a complete answer the question is way too broad.

Comment: @thewaywewalk I think that the main focus is on the physics, an engineer will use his own know-how in physics to explain this, it's basically the same thing.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Thanks for the editing and answering.

Comment: @thewaywewalk the link shows the way to arrange the gain with desired PM. For me I just want to get the gain crossover frequency at a desired Phase Margin. I tried to modify the code but I couldn't.

Comment: @Rayanh I think you misunderstood quite some things in theory, therefore have a look at my answer. If I misunderstood, than you need to rephrase your question and I'm quite sure the answer can be found in the link above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you misunderstood what **Gain Over Frequency** and **phase margin** actually means, and it is not the place to explain it. What I assume you actually want, is a way to evaluate a bode-plot without clicking at it. E.g. you want to know **magnitude** and **frequency** at the point of -20 **phase**.

Let's have a look at these three cases:

---

**Case 1:** you know the frequency and you're searching for magnitude and phase

The easiest case:

```
w = 0.363;                 % specify given frequency
[mag,phase] = bode(Gp,w)   % output of according magnitude and phase
```

returns:

```
mag =

    0.9400


phase =

  -19.9509
```

---

**Case 2:** you want to know magnitude and frequency for a certain phase

```
p = -20;
[mag,phase,wout] = bode(Gp);

mag_p = interp1( squeeze(phase), squeeze(mag), p)
w_p   = interp1( squeeze(phase), wout, p)
```

returns:

```
mag_p =

    0.9394

w_p =

    0.3642
```

---

**Case 3:** you want to know phase and frequency for a certain magnitude

```
m = 0.9394;
[mag,phase,wout] = bode(Gp);

phase_m = interp1( squeeze(mag), squeeze(phase), m)
w_m     = interp1( squeeze(mag), wout, m)
```

returns:

```
phase_m =

  -19.9998


w_m =

    0.3642
```

---

The `squeeze` command is necessary, because bode output a `1x1x...` matrix for phase and magnitude, however. You also may use different interpolation methods of [**`interp1`**](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html).